# When was the Shulchan Aruch HaArizal first published?

Tags: history, books-generally

On HebrewBooks.org they have this edition. Is there any previous edition and when?

מקום דפוס ווילנא 
שנת דפוס תרמא 
Pub. Place Vilna 
Pub. Date 1881 
Pages דפים 95

Answer (score 2, accepted):

שלחן ערוך של האריז"ל דינים וכוונות חדשים גם ישנים וטעמים ע"פ סוד וקבלה כסדר ש"ע או"ח קראקא 1680

Answer (score 3):

Thanks. Here's the 1691 edition, which includes Iggeres Ha-shabbos
http://www.hebrewbooks.org/45674